# Create inverted border radius on stack bar chart

Tags: chart.js

[image]

I'm using the latest chartjs. How can I achieve this inverted border radius in bar chart?

```
const myData = {
  labels: ["1 Jan", "2 Jan", "3 Jan", "4 Jan", "5 Jan", "6 Jan", "7 Jan", "8 Jan"],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Employee',
    backgroundColor: background_1,
    data: [12, 59, 5, 56, 58, 12, 59, 87, 45],
    borderRadius: 100,
    barPercentage: 0.5, // Adjust this value to change the width of the bars
    categoryPercentage: 0.3,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1
  }, {
    label: 'Engineer',
    backgroundColor: background_2,
    data: [12, 59, 5, 56, 58, 12, 59, 85, 23],
    borderRadius: 100,
    barPercentage: 0.5, // Adjust this value to change the width of the bars
    categoryPercentage: 0.3,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderSkipped: 'middle'
  }]
}
```

This is my current data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacked bar charts of chart.js are already
doing most of that.

A first step towards creating the round borders described,
is to set `borderRadius` as an object, so the inner bars
also get rounded corners, e.g.,
`borderRadius: {topLeft: 100, topRight: 100, bottomLeft: 100, bottomRight: 100}`
instead of `borderRadius: 100`,
see [the tip on borderRadius for stacked charts in the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#borderradius).

Then we'll have to extend the second bar under the first (or
nth bar under the previous ones of the same sign and stack), so you get
the "negative radius" effect for the base of the second bar.

This can be achieved by a plugin that does its computations
for instance in the
[`afterDatasetUpdate`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#chart-update)
handler.

One has to keep information about the previous bar,
separate for positive and negative domains, and indexed
by the stack id. All these are details, best seen in
code.

```js
const pluginStackRounded = {// inline plugin, no id
    afterDatasetUpdate(chart, context){
        const plugin = this;
        if(chart.width && chart.height){
            const barElements = context.meta.data,// or chart.getDatasetMeta(context.index).data;
                stackId = context.meta.stack,
                values = context.meta._parsed;
            if(context.index === 0){
                plugin._maxExtension = {};
            }
            if(!plugin._maxExtension[stackId]){
                plugin._maxExtension[stackId] = {
                    positive: Array(values.length).fill(null),
                    negative: Array(values.length).fill(null)
                };
            }

            barElements.forEach(
                (barElement, i) => {
                    const barWidth = barElement.$animations?.width?._active
                            && barElement.$animations?.width._to || barElement.width,
                        barBase = barElement.$animations?.base?._active &&
                            barElement.$animations.base._to || barElement.base,
                        barY = barElement.$animations?.base?._active &&
                            barElement.$animations.y._to || barElement.y,
                        isNegative = barY > barBase; //values[i].y < 0;
                    const maxExtension = 
                        plugin._maxExtension[stackId][isNegative ? "negative" : "positive"][i];
                    if(maxExtension !== null){
                        if(barElement.options.$shared){
                            barElement.options = Object.assign({$shared: false}, barElement.options);
                            barElement.options.borderRadius = Object.assign({}, 
                                barElement.options.borderRadius);
                        }
                        if(!isNegative){
                            barElement.options.borderRadius.bottomLeft = 1;
                            barElement.options.borderRadius.bottomRight = 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            barElement.options.borderRadius.topLeft = 1
                            barElement.options.borderRadius.topRight = 1
                        }
                        if(barElement.$animations?.base?._active){
                            barElement.$animations.base._to = isNegative ?
                                Math.max(barBase - barWidth / 2, maxExtension) :
                                Math.min(barBase + barWidth / 2, maxExtension);
                        }
                        else{
                            barElement.base = isNegative ?
                                Math.max(barElement.base - barWidth, maxExtension) :
                                Math.min(barElement.base + barWidth, maxExtension);
                        }
                    }

                    // update maxExtension for the next dataset
                    const barHeight = barElement.$animations?.height?._active &&
                        barElement.$animations.height._to || barElement.height;
                    if(isNegative){
                        plugin._maxExtension[stackId].negative[i] = barBase + barHeight/2;
                    }
                    else{
                        plugin._maxExtension[stackId].positive[i] = barBase - barHeight/2;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
};

const myData = {
    labels: ["1 Jan", "2 Jan", "3 Jan", "4 Jan", "5 Jan", "6 Jan", "7 Jan", "8 Jan", "9 Jan"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Employee',
            backgroundColor: '#6fd',
            data: [12, 59, 5, 56, 58, 12, 59, 87, 45],
            stack: "A"
        },
        {
            label: 'Engineer',
            backgroundColor: '#fd6',
            data: [12, 59, 5, 56, 58, 12, 59, 85, 23],
            stack: "A"
        }
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: myData,
    plugins:[pluginStackRounded],
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        datasets: {
            bar: {
                barPercentage: 0.25,
                borderRadius: {topLeft: 100, topRight: 100, bottomLeft: 100, bottomRight: 100},
                borderSkipped: false,
                borderColor: 'white',
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        },
        scales:{
            y:{
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 20 // for easy verification on the grid
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
            }
        }
    },
};

new Chart(document.querySelector('#chart1'), config);
```

```html
<div style="min-height: 60vh">
    <canvas id="chart1">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-6HrPqAvK+lZElIZ4mZ64fyxIBTsaX5zAFZg2V/2WT+iKPrFzTzvx6QAsLW2OaLwobhMYBog/+bvmIEEGXi0p1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Hello bro, you're a life saver. You're code rocks didn't how can you do that code. You're a pro. Thanks a lot bro.